# AtmosphereMappingException: Integration within a JBoss application

Tags: rest, jboss, configuration-files, resteasy, atmosphere

I'm trying to add atmosphere with REST inside a JBoss apllication. The intention is to keep the web application running and add a Web Service. (Deployed application via Ant)

I have added the following jars:

- atmosphere-runtime.jar
- jaxrs-api-1.1-RC2.jar
- jboss-seam-resteasy-2.2.0.GA.jar
- resteasy-jaxrs-1.1-RC2.jar

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <description>AtmosphereServlet</description>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/atmosphere/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

atmosphere.xml:

```
<atmosphere-handlers>
    <!-- RESTEasy -->
    <atmosphere-handler support-session="false"
                        context-root="/*/atmosphere"
                        class-name="org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor"
                        interceptorClasses="org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor">
        <property name="servletClassName"
              value="org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamResourceServlet"/>
    </atmosphere-handler>    
</atmosphere-handlers>
```

My java class like this:

```
@Path("/test")
public class Foo {

    @Context HttpServletRequest req;

    @GET
    @Path("/suspend")
    public Response suspend() {
        /*
          AtmosphereResource r = (AtmosphereResource)
                req.getAttribute("org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource");
          r.resumeOnBroadcast(true);
          r.setBroadcaster(BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup("/test", true))
           .suspend();
           */
          return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

URL: http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:8080/posmngr/atmosphere/test

Everytime I try to enter the URL I get the following error:

```
ERROR [[AtmosphereServlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet AtmosphereServlet threw exception
org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereMappingException: No AtmosphereHandler maps request for /posmngr/atmosphere/test/
```

I changed the root-context to "/atmosphere/*" but I get a 404.
 Am I missing something? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: which version of Atmosphere are you using? Try atmosphere-runtime-2.0.0.jar Thanks -- Jeanfrancois

Comment: I'm working with atmosphere 2.1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a litle trickier due to our own framework. I had to integrate atmosphere with spring and seam and consider the order that those are initialized.

My atmosphere.xml context-root now is: `"/atmosphere/*"`

I removed the atmosphere servlet definition from web.xml and placed in an external file that is consumed by spring.

Web.xml fragment:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/servlet/*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and the external file contains:

```
<beans default-lazy-init="true">
    <bean id="atmosphereHandler" class="com.ourcompany.webapp.support.ServletUrlHandlerMapping" parent="abstractHandler">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/atmosphere/**">atmosphereResourceController</prop>              
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="atmosphereResourceController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController"  depends-on="servletContextInitializer">
        <property name="servletClass" value="org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet"/>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

No changes were made to the java and the efective URL  is: http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:8080/posmngr/atmosphere/rest/test/suspend

Thanks a lot!